# How to remove/unload a device tree overlay to program FPGA multiple times?

Tags: embedded-linux, fpga, kernel-module, device-tree

I can program the FPGA part of an Altera/Intel Cyclone V SoC FPGA with a firmware, from Linux on the HPS (ARM core in the SoC FPGA), using Buildroot.
I'm using a device tree overlay to write a raw binary file (.rbf) to the FPGA with configfs.

```sh
mount -t configfs none /sys/kernel/config
mkdir -p /sys/kernel/config/device-tree/overlays/ov_soc_firmware_fpga
echo ov_soc_firmware_fpga.dtb > /sys/kernel/config/device-tree/overlays/ov_soc_firmware_fpga/path
```

But if I issue the `echo` command again, I get this error: *"sh: write error: Operation not permitted"*.
I tried to umount/mount, but it doesn't help.

How can I reprogram the FPGA without rebooting?

Comment: "*I'm using a device tree overlay to write a raw binary file to the FPGA with configfs*" - Really? Or are you confusing the dynamic loading of the DT overlay with the installation of a device driver module? There's a [firmware load API](https://docs.kernel.org/driver-api/firmware/fw_upload.html) that a driver can use during its init() (or when the device is opened). Is that the actual mechanism that is involved in this "DT overlay load" and FPGA "*programming*"? Did you rewiew the syslog (e.g. the **dmesg** command) for salient kernel activity/messages when you perform this DT overlay load?

Comment: @sawdust Yes, that's how the configuration bitstreams are reloaded in newer linuxes. The device tree file contains directive, specifying the path to .rbf file to be used for fpga programming.

Comment: @Vlad - You and the OP seem to be conflating cause and effect (and ignoring what happens in between). The "*directive*" you are presumably referring to is the `firmware-name` property. (DT directives are handled by the DT compiler, and don't exist in the DT after compilation.) The DT is simply data (rather than any "*directives*") to the kernel that describes the HW. According to one driver's use of this property, it is advisory rather than a mandated filename to load. And in that driver (drivers/mfd/iqs62x.c), that DT property is used with that firmware load API that I previously mentioned.

Comment: @sawdust But there is no kernel driver module when you're into fpga development, or have no goal of producing the driver module. You need to load the configuration bitstream, you access the peripherals in the loaded fpga configuration via userspace i/o, so you explicitly load and unload the overlay. The `firmware-name` is not advisory here, it's the absolute necessity to make linux kernel load the bitstream you will be testing into fpga.

Comment: @Vlad - What you call the "*make linux kernel load*" procedure seems to be **fpga_mgr_firmware_load()** in [drivers/fpga/fpga-mgr.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/fpga/fpga-mgr.c#L523). This does use the firmware load API, but this request occurs when the DT overlay is processed, rather than any driver initialization. This is described in [Documentation/devicetree/bindings/fpga/fpga-region.txt](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/fpga/fpga-region.txt)

Comment: @sawdust It's not about fpga-region driver or fpga bridges at all, it's about totally unrelated hardware being created by fpga developer. Reloading the configuration bitstream is irrelevant to fpga bridges, which are hard features and already managed by linux using driver specific to fpga, and which you apparently have in mind. As a developer you design a new device, and then notify linux to do whatever it needs to do on a target platform to pick up new bitstream. This is done by loading the new custom overlay specific to the design, on top of whatever is there loaded for fpga bridges to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unloading the overlay is actually really simple. You do `rmdir /the/path/to/overlay`, and it gets unloaded.

In your case it should be `rmdir /sys/kernel/config/device-tree/overlays/ov_soc_firmware_fpga`.

After unloading you re-run your part starting with `mkdir /path/to/overlay` to get new .rbf loaded.

Note, do not unmount configfs itself.

Comment: It works, thanks. However, when I asked the question, I forgot to mention the boot message : `OF: overlay: WARNING: memory leak will occur if overlay removed, property: /soc/base_fpga_region/firmware-name`. Now, I'm wondering if it is wise to unload (or whatever kernel gurus call it) the DTO. Isn't a good old reboot safer ?

Comment: @dpeng It's expected and shouldn't be the problem. Here's xilinx article, but equally applicable to Intel https://support.xilinx.com/s/article/76560?language=en_US